# How to center align text horizontally and VERTICALLY in a box/container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, center-align

I am trying to create a web page that looks like this:

[Download page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkav8.png)

I worked with bootstrap and created rows to align three download options next to each other. I then created containers in these rows (to replicate the boxes) and center aligned the text and download icon horizontally. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to center align the text and icon vertically in a container. Can anyone help out? My current design looks like this:

[image: Current design]

**My code is the following:**

```css
.download {
  font: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: RGB(112, 112, 112);
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.download:hover {
  color: rgb(227, 111, 30);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download-icon {
  font-size: 80px;
  float: left;
}

.container-border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(0, 143, 197);
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="container-border">
        <i class="material-icons" style="color:rgb(0,143,197);" id="download-icon">file_download</i>
        <p class="download"> Download list of charities that have <b> not submitted </b> data yet </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Thanks everyone for their answers! I really appreciate them. For me it worked by simply adjusting my content-border class with:

```
.container-border {
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgb(0, 143, 197);
padding: 5px;
min-height: 120px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
/* vertical center */
}
```

Comment: Maybe set .container-border to `display: flex` and give it a `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`. That should get you close (depending what other CSS you have going on in there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to complicate stuff using FlexBox. Please use something like this, a table layout or `line-height` and `vertical-align` combination:

```css
.download {
  font: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: RGB(112, 112, 112);
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.download:hover {
  color: rgb(227, 111, 30);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download-icon {
  font-size: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 120px;
}

#download-icon + span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}

.container-border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(0, 143, 197);
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="container-border">
        <i class="material-icons" style="color:rgb(0,143,197);" id="download-icon">file_download</i>
        <span class="download"> Download list of charities that have <b> not submitted </b> data yet </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks Soolie! I tried this solution and it unfortunately did not work for me, even though it logically made total sense to me. I couldn't figure out where the mistake was, so I implemented another solution. But thx a lot anyway!

Comment: Ups, sorry this was my first question on StackOverflow. Just accepted it :)

Comment: @Christina Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `flexbox` for the `container-border` class. In that case you can remove the floats.

```css
.download {
  font: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: RGB(112, 112, 112);
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.download:hover {
  color: rgb(227, 111, 30);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download-icon {
  font-size: 80px;
}

.container-border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(0, 143, 197);
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* vertical center */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="container-border">
        <i class="material-icons" style="color:rgb(0,143,197);" id="download-icon">file_download</i>
        <p class="download"> Download list of charities that have <b> not submitted </b> data yet </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerard, I implemented your solution and it worked!! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

add `display: flex;align-items: center;` to `.container-border`

```
.container-border{
 border-style:solid;
 border-color: rgb(0,143,197);
 padding: 5px;
 min-height:120px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set a padding:

```
.download {
    font: Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: RGB(112,112,112);
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    /* padding: 5px; <- removed */
    padding: 12px 5px 5px 5px; /* New */
}

#download-icon {
    font-size:80px;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 10px; /* New */
}

.container-border {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: rgb(0,143,197);
    padding: 5px;
    min-height:120px;
    width: 300px; /* New*/
}
```

Demo:

```css
.download {
    font: Verdana,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: RGB(112,112,112);
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    /* padding: 5px; <- removed */
    padding: 12px 5px 5px 5px; /* New */
}

.download:hover {
    color: rgb(227,111,30);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#download-icon {
    font-size:80px;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 10px; /* New */
}

.container-border {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: rgb(0,143,197);
    padding: 5px;
    min-height:120px;
    width: 300px; /* New*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="container-border">
                <i class="material-icons" style="color:rgb(0,143,197);" id="download-icon">file_download</i>
                <p class="download"> Download list of charities that have <b> not submitted                 </b> data yet </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Being a regular user (with 729 rep), why can't you use a Stack Snippet?

Comment: @Soolie Because I didn't want to add a demo here with bloated CSS code. Look at the fiddle. I had to add the code for the icon as well. Despite that, I don't see anything wrong with using JSFiddle.

Comment: I am under a corporate network and I couldn't access the site. Happens with most of them. And also there's a chance of link rot. :)

Comment: @NullDev I know size doesn't matter. But with 300px you have the smallest one :)

Comment: @Gerard Haha, well, judging by the screenshots, OP doesn't want a that long one ;)